# how inadvertently adding UTF8 format while copy paste?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, editor

I have a string with non uft8 format 
`$str = Processing’s`;

following json_encode works fine because i'm copying and pasting code to my editor

```
$str = Processing’s;
echo json_encode($str);
```

output:

```
Processing\u2019s"
```

if i retrive the same string `Processing’s` from DB and do `json_encode` it returns `NULL` because of it is non UTF8 string.

How when I copy paste code works like UTF8 encoded string? what happens when I copy and Paste the codes?

Comment: Probably because your database is using a different encoding.

Comment: OS X and Window's clipboard maintains Unicode characters either by converting to UTF-16 or by recording the encoding. When copying between apps, it's the editor/viwer that determines the encoding not the clipboard